# Wordpress Redirects When a Query String Contains a Number

Tags: url-rewriting, query

I have a URL query string containing a number and it redirects and gives a 404 error as the page does not exist. If I change the value of the parameter to characters it works.  I'm guessing it's something to do with wordpress pagenation.

Examples

https://www.ppc.com.au/ndeftest?m=23345 'redirects 404 error

https://www.ppc.com.au/ndeftest?m=test 'does not redirect - works as required

I need to pass the number variable to the page.  It comes from a standard NTAG feature on smartcards that automatically appends the card serial number to the URL so I don't have many options to change the URL appearance.

(the code on the landing page is not correct, but I will fix that once the parameter is passed)

Comment: `m` is the query var for year/month, see [Reserved Terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) for a list of query string vars that you should avoid.

Comment: Thanks, Milo, no it's not a year/month so that may be the problem if I change the m to something else it works.  I'm not sure I can change the m in the application but will take it up with them.

Comment: Hi Milo, if you post that as the answer I will confirm it - thank you again.

Comment: was getting this when trying to do p=2, using pg=2 works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` is the built-in query var for year/month, see [Reserved Terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) for a list of query string vars that you should avoid.